# %2F instead of slash in url?

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

I have a problem with jquery syntax in an url link:

this is the link i am getting (englisch):

> ...myaccount/?lang=en%2Fprint-order%2F2067%2F&print-order-type=receipt

this is the german link:

> ...myaccount/print-order/2067/?print-order-type=receipt

the problem now is, that the link looks ok in my browser

> myaccount/print-order/2067/?print-order-type=receipt

but actually there's always a "%2F" instead of a "/" inside the link when I copy it which leads to the problem of getting an 404.

When I manually replace "%2F" the link works.

Where is the problem? Any idea to fix this?

The code below comes from woocommerce/templates/myaccount/my-orders.php

```
if ($actions) { foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ) { echo '<a
 href="' . esc_url( $action['url'] ) . '" class="button ' .
 sanitize_html_class( $key ) . '">' . esc_html( $action['name'] ) .
 '</a>'; }
```

It generates the "Print" button on the "my orders" page. I am using mqtranslate german/englisch. In  the german version everything works- the links are correct, ony when i switch the language there are "%2f" instead of "/". But also only after the first part (until myaccount/) - because some "/" are correctly encoded.

Also in the english version it's a "&" before "print-order-type=receipt" instead of a "?".

Comment: Don't really know what effect jquery or javascript has on your URL problem?

Comment: Show the jQuery code you are using.

Comment: yeah sorry, maybe it's not jquery problem - I thought so first. I added code from the file, where it is generated

Comment: In the first url it looks like you have 2 query strings: `myaccount/?lang=en%2Fprint-order%2F2067%2F?print-order-type=receipt`. It looks as if the second url `print-order/2067/?print-order-type=receipt` was appended to `myaccount/?lang=en`

Comment: Hi Daniel, yes, that's true - I am using mqtranslate and removed this code with jquery - "href.replace"  that's why I first tought it has something to do with jquery. But it hasn't. I think it is this "esc_url" - but I don't know where to change this. Neither it has really something to do with this...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) on the copied value:

```
decodeURIComponent('myaccount/?lang=en%2Fprint-order%2F2067%2F?print-order-type=receipt')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7hySU/

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for suggestion, but the code is dynamically. So the url changes for every item.

Comment: @ad2003 You can just pass the dynamic value to that function

Comment: Thanks so much! Works now!

Answer (score 2):

do this:

```
echo '<a href="' . urldecode($action['url'] ) ....
```

More about this:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

urldecode() is doing egzactly what you are looking for. Just apply it in your foreach loop.

This will solve your problem

Cheers :)

You can try it at http://3v4l.org/mhVuV kind of phpfiddle :)

put this in the box:

```
    echo urldecode("myaccount/?lang=en%2Fprint-order%2F2067%2F&print-order-type=receipt");
```